# Shifting axes with matrices

Tags: matrices, vectors, solution-verification

If I would like to shift the $x$ axis onto the line $a_1x+b_1y=0$ and the $y$ axes onto the line $a_2x+b_2y=0$ is the following operation correct?

$\begin{pmatrix}
x ' \\
y'  \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 \\
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y  \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1x+b_1y  \\
a_2x+b_2y \\
\end{pmatrix}$

is this correct?

Comment: You don’t have enough information here to determine the transformation uniquely: you haven’t said what the unit lengths should be on each of the new axes, and there’s also a choice of direction for each one that you seem to be making implicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the origin is certainly mapped correctly. If you are on the $x$-axis, in other words $y=0$, your map results in $x(a_1,a_2)^T$ which is not what you would like. Ditto $x=0$, which results in $y(b_1,b_2)^T$, instead of being on the second line you specified.

Do you see how to change your transformation to make it work?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @gt6989b. I have a question; is what I have written $\begin{pmatrix}
a_1x & b_1y  \\
a_2x & b_2y\\
\end{pmatrix}$ equivalent to mapping the x axis to $y=\frac{a_2}{a_1}x$ and the y axis to $y=\frac{b_2}{b_1}x$ ?

Comment: @MathsWizzard indeed, that is correct. You can see that directly from the argument in my answer...

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I now see that the desired matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 \\
-b_1 & -b_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$. Just a quick question about matrix transformations in general. When I was matching $x'$ with the first line to get $x'=a_1x+b_1y$ is this expression just telling me how each $x'$ could be calculated rather than where the new $x'$ axis is?

Comment: @MathsWizzard yes, but the trick to getting the matrix right is to see origin and unit vectors in each direction mapped into sensible places.